# DownloaderClientMarshaller

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Была проблема с импортом из Eclipse в Android Studio. Посоветовали добавить библиотеку в `app.gradle`

Собственно, вот ответ:

> " because you need to get another
> library for
> "DownloaderClientMarshaller" as this
> is not located by android studio, I
> believe there must be a library for
> this or some ways to add it to
> "app.gradle",
>
> If you are able to get jar file for
> library what you can do is make a
> "lib" directory inside root directory
> of project and put that library there
> and mention in "app.gradle" that you
> want android studio to add another
> library."

Как именно это нужно сделать? Гугл ничего дельного не дает.